# How can I change the shortcut keys for my MacBook Pro so it doesn't conflict with my remote Windows shortcuts?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, keyboard, ms-office, windows

From my MacBook Pro, I use a Java program that allows me to remotely connect to my Windows computer.  I use Outlook on this Windows computer where normally I use shortcut keys like <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd> to categories emails in Outlook.

So for <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> it actually works fine but I need to press <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd>. The issue is when I press <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd> it seems that it's an Apple shortcut to rotate through apps, so it trumps what I am actually trying to do on the Windows machine.

Is there any workaorund to this issue? Is there a way I can turn off some of the Apple shortcuts or anything else to deal with this?

### Update

I created a bounty to answer the question that I listed as a comment on the first answer:

What is weird is that F2 and F4 are both checked so I don't understand why F2 works but F4 doesn't in my Outlook. Also, after unchecking F4 and trying to categorize in Outlook the shortcut still doesn't work. After turning off all of the Apple shortcuts, it seems that F2, F6, and F8 work but others don't. Any explanation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable some of the F-key shortcuts in System Preferences:
[image]

Comment: thanks . . what is weird is that F2 and F4 are both checked so i don't understand why F2 works but F4 doesn't in my outlook.  also, after unchecking F4 and trying to categorize in outlook the shortcut still doesn't work.  After turning off all of the apple shortcuts, it seems like F2, F6, F8 work but others don't . .any explanation ?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at our application [ShortStop](http://mizage.com/shortstop/) which was made specifically for sending shortcuts through remote screen sessions.

Comment: Not only am I a big fan of your work, I appreciate the participation and self-disclosure that you are discussing your products.

Answer (score 3):

Just a suggestion: Look at the key mapping in windows and not the Mac side.  remember that while Command is often control in windows, often times the option, fn, and control keys can be swapped.

Answer (score 2):

It's not easy to test if it work without having your Java program and your windows environment.

However in `Settings` > `Keyboard` there is a flag `Use all F1, F2, etc keys as standard function keys`. If you check it you have to press <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>Fx</kbd> for using the special features printed on the <kbd>Fx</kbd> keys.

[image: Keyboard settings]

On my system (Mountain Lion), when this flag is unchecked <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> produces the effect you reported: rotate through apps. This is the shortcut mentioned in Lauri Ranta's answer. When I check the flag the keys combination doesn't produced the mentioned rotation. You can try to uncheck it.

If your problem persist you can try to remap shortcut under Windows, in this way you can assign the command associated to <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to another combination which is not used under OS X.

In [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/318641/how-do-you-change-the-ctrlenter-keyboard-shortcut-in-outlook-2007) on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) they said that it's not possible to change <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> shortcuts under Outloook. However they suggest to use AutoHotKey to assign a script that sends <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to Outlook when you press another combination of keys (which you can decide). [Here](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) you can find more information.